# Тест на jquery с использованием нескольких checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь допилить тест.

Есть вопрос с несколькими вариантами ответа, и кнопка "Проверить". Нужно что бы пользователь выбирал варианты ответа, жал на кнопку "Проверить" и видел подсказки, которые изначально спрятаны. 
Сейчас есть только только такая версия

```js
$('input.showorhide').click(function () {
                var checked = $(this).siblings("input.showorhide:checked");
                $(this).siblings('div.showorhide').hide();
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(this).siblings('div#' + $(this).val()).show();
                    $(this).siblings('input').prop('checked', false);
                };
            });
```

```css
.kd-special-test {
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #838494;
                width: 100%;
                min-width: 730px;
                max-width: 730px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
            }
            .kd-special-test label p{
                margin: 0px 0px -11px 0px;
                padding-top: 3px;
            }
            .kd-special-test label p.special2{
                 margin-top: -5px;
            }     
            .kd-special-test p span {
                color: #00B7EF;
            }
            .kd-special-test h2{
                font-size: 22px;
                color: #000;
                letter-spacing: -0.014em;
                line-height: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 0.8em;
                margin-top: 1em;
            }
            .kd-special-test__hidden {
                display: none;
                background: #ebebeb;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
            }
            .kd-special-test__hidden p {
                padding: 25px 10px 20px 10px;
                display: none;
            }
            .kd-special-test .showorhide.block {
                display: none;
            }
            .kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles  p {
                font-family: Arial !important;
                font-size: 15px !important;
                font-weight: normal;
                line-height: 22px !important;
            }
            .kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles  p:nth-child(1) {
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
            .kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles {
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 1.42857143;
                font-weight: 100;
                padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
                margin: 20px 10px 25px 0;
                -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                border-radius: 15px;

            }
            .kd-special-test__risk {
                background: #E13E00;
            }
            .kd-special-test__recommend {
                background: #42C98C;
            }
            .kd-special-test label:hover  {
                height: 30px;
                border: solid 1px #838494;

            }
            /*Стилизация чекбоксов    */
            .kd-special-test label {
                width: 94.6%;
                border-left: solid 1px #fff;
                border-top: solid 1px #fff;
                border-bottom: solid 1px #fff;
                display: inline-table;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;
                padding-left: 40px;
                margin: 5px 15px 5px 0;
                height: 30px;

            }
            .kd-special-test input[type=checkbox] {
                display: none;
            }

            .kd-special-test label:before {
                content: "";
                display: inline-block;
                width: 26px;
                height: 26px;
                margin-right: 10px;
                position: absolute;
                left: -1px;
                bottom: 0;
                border: 3px solid #ff9900;
            }
            @-moz-document url-prefix() {
                .kd-special-test label:before {
                    content: "";
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 27px;
                    height: 27px;
                    margin-right: 10px;
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 0;
                    bottom: 0;
                    border: 4px solid #ff9900;
                }
            }
            .kd-special-test input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
                background: url(http://service.kdelo.ru/images/check.png) no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                background-position: 0 0;
            }
            @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

                .kd-special-test{
                    width: 90%;
                    min-width: inherit;
                }
                .kd-special-test label{
                    width: 87%;
                }
                .kd-special-test label p {
                    margin: 9px 0 0 0;
                    line-height: 12px !important;
                    padding-top: 0px;
                    padding-left: 10px;
                }
                .kd-special-test label:before {
                    content: "";
                    display: inline-block;
                    width: 33px;
                    height: 33px;
                }
                .kd-special-test label:hover  {
                    border: none;
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="kd-special-test">
            <h2>Вопрос</h2>
        
            <input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q1_1" id="q1_1"/>      <label for="q1_1"><p>Да</p></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q2_1" id="q2_1"/>      <label for="q2_1"><p>Нет</p></label>
            <input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q3_1" id="q3_1" />     <label for="q3_1"><p>Наверное</p></label>
            
            <div id="q1_1" class="showorhide block" >
           
                <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__risk">
                    <p>Пояснение 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="q2_1" class="showorhide block" >
                <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__risk">
                    
                    <p>Пояснение 2</p>
                </div>
          
            </div>

            <div id="q3_1" class="showorhide block" >
                <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__recommend">
                    
                    <p>Пояснение 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
<button type="button">Показать результаты</button>
        </div>
```

где все варианты показываются последовательно.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вариант, как можно реализовать с кнопкой.

Comment: С какой кнопкой? Которая "Проверить" ? Добавьте кнопку, повесьте обработчик на кнопку, а не на checbox'ы. Пробегитесь по всем checbox'ам и выведете подсказки только активных

Comment: @ArchDemon, пробежаться циклом? можно какой нибудь абстрактный пример, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Например, так. Код является не оптимальным, но показывает основной принцип

```js
$('div #showresult').click(function() {
  $('.kd-special-test input[type=checkbox]').each(function(e) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('div#' + $(this).val()).show();
    } else {
      $('div#' + $(this).val()).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.kd-special-test {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #838494;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 730px;
  max-width: 730px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.kd-special-test h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: -0.014em;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.kd-special-test__hidden {
  display: none;
  background: #ebebeb;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.kd-special-test__hidden p {
  padding: 25px 10px 20px 10px;
  display: none;
}

.kd-special-test .showorhide.block {
  display: none;
}

.kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles p {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 15px !important;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 22px !important;
}

.kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin: 20px 10px 25px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.kd-special-test__risk {
  background: #E13E00;
}

.kd-special-test__recommend {
  background: #42C98C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="kd-special-test">
  <h2>Вопрос</h2>

  <label><input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q1_1" />Да</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q2_1" />Нет</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="showorhide" value="q3_1" />Наверное</label>

  <div id="q1_1" class="showorhide block">

    <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__risk">
      <p>Пояснение 1</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="q2_1" class="showorhide block">
    <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__risk">

      <p>Пояснение 2</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="q3_1" class="showorhide block">
    <div class="kd-special-test__hidden-block-styles kd-special-test__recommend">

      <p>Пояснение 3</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="showresult">Показать результаты</button>
</div>
```